# China. Its very own modular spacestation

Tags: iss, space-station, cnsa, tiangong-2, tiangong-space-station

China future plan for spacestation after the lost testbed are more and more turning into reality by time. Now with Long March 5/7 success when will China launch its spacestation and how will it differ from Iss?

Comment: China already launched a space station and you can read about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiangong-1

Comment: Well, then i am talking about its next iteration the -2 . 
Some say they have lost control/communication with first?

Comment: You can read about the answer to your revised question here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiangong_program

Comment: I think they will release more imfo on it i seek with time/soon. i will keep my eyes on this

Answer (score 1):

A bit dated (2011) [article](http://europe.chinadaily.com.cn/china/2011-04/26/content_12395890.htm) from China Daily states that the launch of Tiangong-3 is planned around 2020-2022, stating that this is information from The China Manned Space Engineering Office. The guardian had an [article from around the same time](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2011/apr/26/china-space-station-tiangong), giving a similar time range. A [more recent article](http://www.spacedaily.com/reports/Chinas_Space_Station_is_Still_On_Track_999.html) from Space Daily states that the plan is not changed.

Some core differences between Tiangong-3 and the ISS is that while the ISS is an international project using modules from several countries, the Russia and the US being the main partners, China plans to build their station entirely by themselves. Structurally, the station is going to look more like [Mir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mir), with modules clustered in a cross around a single central docking node. In contrast, the ISS is built around several nodes and beams.